# How do I create a HashMap literal?

Tags: hashmap, rust

How I can create a HashMap literal in Rust? In Python I can do it so:

```py
hashmap = {
   'element0': {
       'name': 'My New Element',
       'childs': {
           'child0': {
               'name': 'Child For Element 0',
               'childs': {
                   ...
               }
           }
       }
   },
   ...
}
```

And in Go like this:

```golang
type Node struct {
    name string
    childs map[string]Node
}

hashmap := map[string]Node {
    "element0": Node{
        "My New Element",
        map[string]Node {
            'child0': Node{
                "Child For Element 0",
                map[string]Node {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 215, accepted):

There isn't a map literal syntax in Rust. I don't know the *exact* reason, but I expect that the fact that there are multiple data structures that act maplike (such as both [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html) and [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html)) would make it hard to pick one.

## Rust 1.56

Many collections now offer conversions from an array argument using  `From` or `Into`:

```rust
use std::collections::{BTreeMap, BTreeSet, HashMap, HashSet};

fn main() {
    let s = Vec::from([1, 2, 3]);
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s = BTreeSet::from([1, 2, 3]);
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s = HashSet::from([1, 2, 3]);
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s = BTreeMap::from([(1, 2), (3, 4)]);
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s = HashMap::from([(1, 2), (3, 4)]);
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

This logic can be wrapped back into a macro for some syntax sugar:

```rust
use std::collections::{BTreeMap, BTreeSet, HashMap, HashSet};

macro_rules! collection {
    // map-like
    ($($k:expr => $v:expr),* $(,)?) => {{
        core::convert::From::from([$(($k, $v),)*])
    }};
    // set-like
    ($($v:expr),* $(,)?) => {{
        core::convert::From::from([$($v,)*])
    }};
}

fn main() {
    let s: Vec<_> = collection![1, 2, 3];
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s: BTreeSet<_> = collection! { 1, 2, 3 };
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s: HashSet<_> = collection! { 1, 2, 3 };
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s: BTreeMap<_, _> = collection! { 1 => 2, 3 => 4 };
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s: HashMap<_, _> = collection! { 1 => 2, 3 => 4 };
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

## Rust 1.51

As of Rust 1.51, you can use by-value array iterators and `FromIterator` to collect into many kinds of collections:

```rust
use std::array::IntoIter;
use std::collections::{BTreeMap, BTreeSet, HashMap, HashSet};
use std::iter::FromIterator;

fn main() {
    // Rust 1.53
    let s = Vec::from_iter([1, 2, 3]);
    println!("{:?}", s);

    // Rust 1.51
    let s = Vec::from_iter(IntoIter::new([1, 2, 3]));
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s = BTreeSet::from_iter(IntoIter::new([1, 2, 3]));
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s = HashSet::<_>::from_iter(IntoIter::new([1, 2, 3]));
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s = BTreeMap::from_iter(IntoIter::new([(1, 2), (3, 4)]));
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s = HashMap::<_, _>::from_iter(IntoIter::new([(1, 2), (3, 4)]));
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

Note that in Rust 1.53, `std::array::IntoIter` isn't always needed.

This logic can be wrapped back into a macro for some syntax sugar:

```rust
use std::collections::{BTreeMap, BTreeSet, HashMap, HashSet};

macro_rules! collection {
    // map-like
    ($($k:expr => $v:expr),* $(,)?) => {{
        use std::iter::{Iterator, IntoIterator};
        Iterator::collect(IntoIterator::into_iter([$(($k, $v),)*]))
    }};
    // set-like
    ($($v:expr),* $(,)?) => {{
        use std::iter::{Iterator, IntoIterator};
        Iterator::collect(IntoIterator::into_iter([$($v,)*]))
    }};
}

fn main() {
    let s: Vec<_> = collection![1, 2, 3];
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s: BTreeSet<_> = collection! { 1, 2, 3 };
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s: HashSet<_> = collection! { 1, 2, 3 };
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s: BTreeMap<_, _> = collection! { 1 => 2, 3 => 4 };
    println!("{:?}", s);

    let s: HashMap<_, _> = collection! { 1 => 2, 3 => 4 };
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

These solutions avoid both unneeded allocation and reallocation.

See also:

- [Add hashmap, hashset, treemap, and treeset macros](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/542)

## Previous versions

You can create a macro to do the job for you, as demonstrated in [Why does this rust HashMap macro no longer work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276617). Here is that macro simplified a bit and with enough structure to make it [runnable in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=00384ccaca8d2eaf5b2e6ef7229e6e05&version=stable):

```rust
macro_rules! map(
    { $($key:expr => $value:expr),+ } => {
        {
            let mut m = ::std::collections::HashMap::new();
            $(
                m.insert($key, $value);
            )+
            m
        }
     };
);

fn main() {
    let names = map!{ 1 => "one", 2 => "two" };
    println!("{} -> {:?}", 1, names.get(&1));
    println!("{} -> {:?}", 10, names.get(&10));
}
```

This macro avoids allocating an unneeded intermediate `Vec`, but it doesn't use [`HashMap::with_capacity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.with_capacity) so there may be some useless reallocations of the `HashMap` as values are added. A more complicated version of the macro that counts the values is possible, but the performance benefits are probably not something most uses of the macro would benefit from.

Comment: There's also one in the `grabbag_macros` crate.  You can see the source here: https://github.com/DanielKeep/rust-grabbag/blob/master/grabbag_macros/src/lib.rs#L3-L64.

Comment: Ah, shame. I like Swift approach to this, which abstracts literals from their types. A [`DictionaryLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionaryliteral) can be used to initialize any type that conforms to [`ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebydictionaryliteral) (even though the standard library offers one such type, [`Dictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary))

Comment: With the stabilization of `std::array::IntoIter` in Rust 1.51, you no longer need nightly for the second method.

Comment: Worth mentioning Rust 1.56's `HashMap::from([ ("k1",1), ("k2",2) ])`

Answer (score 76):

I recommend the [maplit](https://docs.rs/maplit/1.0.2/maplit/) crate.

To quote from the documentation:

> Macros for container literals with specific type.

```rust
use maplit::hashmap;

let map = hashmap!{
    "a" => 1,
    "b" => 2,
};
```

> The maplit crate uses `=>` syntax for the mapping macros. It is not possible to use `:` as separator due to syntactic the restrictions in regular `macro_rules!` macros.
>
> Note that rust macros are flexible in which brackets you use for the invocation. You can use them as `hashmap!{}` or `hashmap![]` or `hashmap!()`. This crate suggests `{}` as the convention for the map & set macros, it matches their Debug output.
>
> Macros
>
> - `btreemap`  Create a `BTreeMap` from a list of key-value pairs
> - `btreeset`  Create a `BTreeSet` from a list of elements.
> - `hashmap`   Create a `HashMap` from a list of key-value pairs
> - `hashset`   Create a `HashSet` from a list of elements.

Answer (score 54):

There is an example of how to achieve this in the [documentation for `HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html):

```rust
let timber_resources: HashMap<&str, i32> = [("Norway", 100), ("Denmark", 50), ("Iceland", 10)]
    .iter()
    .cloned()
    .collect();
```

Comment: While it works in this case, it becomes needlessly expensive when using something like `String` instead of `&str`.

Comment: Sure there are runtime costs, but there are also costs associated with adding another crate dependency or with defining hard-to-understand macros. Most code is not performance critical and I find this version very readable.

Comment: Additionally, this doesn't work for types that aren't Clone.

Comment: This example can be tuned to avoid those issues, by using `vec![ (name, value) ].into_iter().collect()`

Comment: @jupp0r why bother write in Rust if you doesn't want performance ? I don't get this. You don't need to understand the detail implementation of a macro to use it.

Comment: @Stargateur because I don't do premature optimization and neither should you. It might be that your program would benefit from more optimized HashMap literal initialization, but it probably won't. If you want to get the best performance, measure and optimize the parts of your program that are on the critical path. Randomly optimizing stuff is just a bad strategy. My answer will be fine for 99.9999% of people. It's readable, compiles fast, does not introduce dependencies that increase complexity and introduce potential security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @jupp0r "premature optimization" is not that

Comment: Yeah, a syntax like hashmap![("Norway",100)] would make things more readable and would absolutely not be a sort of "premature optimization". It's even shorter to write! It really should be in the std-lib I think.

Comment: @Stargateur optimizing anything without data-driven evidence that the optimization will yield tangible results is premature.

Comment: This isn't really about prematurely optimizing, it's about not prematurely pessimizing. https://elegantchaos.com/2014/10/27/premature-pessimization-and-the-like.html

Comment: Adding a new dependency to your project just to declare a hashmap literal is prematurely optimizing.

Answer (score 32):

Starting with Rust 1.56, you can initialize a HashMap using `from()`, which is somewhat like having a HashMap literal.  `from()` takes an array of key-value pairs.  You can use it like this:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let hashmap = HashMap::from([
        ("foo", 1),
        ("bar", 2)
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As noted by @Johannes in the comments, it's possible to use `vec![]` because:

- `Vec<T>` implements the `IntoIterator<T>` trait
- `HashMap<K, V>` implements `FromIterator<Item = (K, V)>`

which means you can do this:

```
let map: HashMap<String, String> = vec![("key".to_string(), "value".to_string())]
    .into_iter()
    .collect();
```

You can use `&str` but you might need to annotate lifetimes if it's not `'static`:

```
let map: HashMap<&str, usize> = vec![("one", 1), ("two", 2)].into_iter().collect();
```

Comment: Will this not represent the vector literal in the binary then collect it into a hashmap at runtime?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`velcro`](https://docs.rs/velcro/latest/velcro/) crate*. It is similar to `maplit`, as recommended in other answers, but with more collection types, better syntax (in my opinion at least!) and more features.

Assuming you want to use `String`s rather than `&str`, your exact example would look like this:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use velcro::hash_map;

struct Node {
    name: String
    children: HashMap<String, Node>,
}

let map = hash_map! {
    String::from("element0"): Node {
        name: "My New Element".into(),
        children: hash_map! {
            String::from("child0"): Node {
                name: "child0".into(),
                children: hash_map!{}
            }
        }
    }
};
```

That's a bit ugly because of how `String`s are constructed. But it can be made a bit cleaner, without changing the key type, by using `hash_map_from!` which will automatically do conversions:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use velcro::{hash_map, hash_map_from};

let map: HashMap<String, Node> = hash_map_from! {
    "element0": Node {
        name: "My New Element".into(),
        children: hash_map_from! {
            "child0": Node {
                name: "child0".into(),
                children: hash_map!{}
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Which isn't *much* more verbose than the Go version.

---

*<sub>*Full disclosure: I am the author of this crate.*</sub>

Answer (score 4):

As of Rust 1.51, `IntoIterator` is implemented for arrays, so you can create a `HashMap` with the `from_iter` method without cloning:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::iter::FromIterator;

// note that this type annotation is required
let mut map: HashMap<_, _> = HashMap::from_iter([("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)]);
```

And as of Rust 1.56 (currently nightly), you can use the `From<[(K, V); N]>` implementation, which is even cleaner:

```rust
let mut map = HashMap::from([
    ("a", 1),
    ("b", 2),
    ("c", 3),
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

### For one element

If you wish to initialize the map with only one element in one line (and without visible mutation in your code), you could do:

```rust
let map: HashMap<&'static str, u32> = Some(("answer", 42)).into_iter().collect();
```

This is thanks to the usefulness of [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option) being able to become an [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) using [`into_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-IntoIterator-2).

In real code, you probably don't need to help the compiler with the type:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn john_wick() -> HashMap<&'static str, u32> {
    Some(("answer", 42)).into_iter().collect()
}

fn main() {
    let result = john_wick();

    let mut expected = HashMap::new();
    expected.insert("answer", 42);

    assert_eq!(result, expected);
}
```

There is also a way to chain this to have more than one element doing something like `Some(a).into_iter().chain(Some(b).into_iter()).collect()`, but this is longer, less readable and probably has some optimization issues, so I advise against it.

Answer (score -3):

I have seen a bunch of fancy solutions, but I wanted something simple. To that end, here is a trait:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait Hash {
    fn to_map(&self) -> HashMap<&str, u16>;
}

impl Hash for [(&str, u16)] {
    fn to_map(&self) -> HashMap<&str, u16> {
        self.iter().cloned().collect()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let m = [("year", 2019), ("month", 12)].to_map();
    println!("{:?}", m)
}
```

I think it's a good option, as it's essentially what's already used by [Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-to_h) and [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tables.html#toTable,openArray%5B%5D).

Comment: "I think its a good option, as its essentially whats already used by Ruby and Nim" I don't understand how this is a argument ? why ruby or Nim do this would be a better argument then just "they do that so it's good"

Comment: an opinion without argument is not useful in a SO answer

Comment: A detail: calling the trait "Hash" is a bad idea: there's already a trait with that name and you'll fast encounter it when working with hashing in rust.

Comment: I would also advice to prefer `copied()` to disallow type that don't implement copy, avoiding cloning for nothing, or at least make it explicit using a cloned_to_map() if you also want to be able to do that with only cloned type.