# How do I create a map from a list in a functional way?

Tags: rust

In Scala, there is a method named `toMap` that works on any list of tuples and converts it to a map where the key is the first item on the tuple and the value is the second one:

```scala
val listOfTuples = List(("one", 1), ("two", 2))
val map = listOfTuples.toMap
```

What is the closest thing to `toMap` in Rust?

Comment: In short: `use std::collections::HashMap; let map: HashMap<&str, u32> = [("a", 5), ("b", 6), ("a", 7)].into_iter().collect(); println!("{:?}", map); // sometimes {"b": 6, "a": 7}, sometimes {"a": 6, "b": 7}` (note that the merging behaviour seems to be "use latest")

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Use [`Iterator::collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let tuples = [("one", 1), ("two", 2), ("three", 3)];
    let m: HashMap<_, _> = tuples.into_iter().collect();
    println!("{:?}", m);
}
```

`collect` leverages the [`FromIterator` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html). Any iterator can be collected into a type that implements `FromIterator`. In this case, `HashMap` implements it as:

```
impl<K, V, S> FromIterator<(K, V)> for HashMap<K, V, S>
where
    K: Eq + Hash,
    S: HashState + Default,
```

Said another way, any iterator of tuples where the first value can [be hashed](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hash.html) and [compared for total equality](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html) can be converted to a `HashMap`. The `S` parameter isn't exciting to talk about, it just defines what the hashing method is.

With this knowledge, you can also call `FromIterator` directly:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let m: HashMap<_, _> = HashMap::from_iter([("one", 1), ("two", 2), ("three", 3)]);
    println!("{:?}", m);
}
```

See also:

- [Collect iterators of length 2 into HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47802539/155423)
- [How do I create a HashMap literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27582739/155423)

---

> what change should I make so that I get all the values with same key stored in a `Vec`?

There's no one-line / functional method for this in the standard library. Instead, use the [`entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) API:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let tuples = vec![("one", 1), ("two", 2), ("one", 3)];
    let mut m = HashMap::new();
    for (k, v) in tuples {
        m.entry(k).or_insert_with(Vec::new).push(v)
    }
    println!("{:?}", m);
}
```

If you found yourself doing this frequently, you could create your own type and implement `FromIterator` for it:

```
use std::{cmp::Eq, collections::HashMap, hash::Hash, iter::FromIterator};

struct MyCoolType<K: Eq + Hash, V>(HashMap<K, Vec<V>>);

impl<K: Eq + Hash, V> FromIterator<(K, V)> for MyCoolType<K, V> {
    fn from_iter<I>(tuples: I) -> Self
    where
        I: IntoIterator<Item = (K, V)>,
    {
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        for (k, v) in tuples {
            m.entry(k).or_insert_with(Vec::new).push(v)
        }
        Self(m)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tuples = vec![("one", 1), ("two", 2), ("one", 3)];
    let MyCoolType(m) = tuples.into_iter().collect();
    println!("{:?}", m);
}
```

See also:

- [How to lookup from and insert into a HashMap efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28512394/155423)

Comment: Nice, so the `FromIterator` is Rust's `CanBuildFrom` :) (I know it's not but it's surely easier to understand...)

Comment: What we have duplicate keys: `let tuples = vec![("one", 1), ("two", 2), ("one", 11)];`. How does the current solution behave? And what change should I make so that I get all the values with _same_ key stored in a `Vec`?

Comment: @Nawaz *How does the current solution behave* — does something prevent you from trying this yourself? The [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) is an excellent resource for that type of question.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Yes, I should have tried that on the playground. Thanks. :-).. and thanks for the updating the solution as well. I came up with [almost same solution, using `fold` though instead of explicit `for` loop](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d5a652229d6c44f8e68432f33cf4c7c0):

Answer (score 9):

```
let map = HashMap::from([
  ("one", 1), 
  ("two", 2)
]);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=89b1ddb20fa048d27f529b41cb87ce0d)

Comment: While @Shepmaster's answer is more thorough and informative, Kamil's provides the most straightforward solution.  Perhaps Shepmaster could update his answer to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Since it wasn't already mentioned, here is a single line (albeit long) method:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
   let m: HashMap<&str, u16> = [("year", 2019), ("month", 12)].iter().cloned().collect();
   println!("{:?}", m);
}
```

Or you can do a Trait:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait Hash {
   fn to_map(&self) -> HashMap<&str, u16>;
}

impl Hash for [(&str, u16)] {
   fn to_map(&self) -> HashMap<&str, u16> {
      self.iter().cloned().collect()
   }
}

fn main() {
   let m = [("year", 2019), ("month", 12)].to_map();
   println!("{:?}", m)
}
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#examples