# Collect iterators of length 2 into HashMap

Tags: rust

I'm able to parse my input into effectively an `Iterator<Iterator<i32>>` where each inner iterator is length 2. The input looks like:

```
0: 3
1: 2
2: 4
4: 8
6: 5
8: 6
...
```

I can parse this with:

```
input.lines()
     .map(|line| line.split(": ")
                     .filter_map(|n| n.parse::<i32>().ok()))
```

The best way I came up with to put this into a `HashMap` is:

```
let mut tmp_map: HashMap<i32, i32> = HashMap::new();
for mut pair in input.lines()
                     .map(|line| line.split(": ")
                                     .filter_map(|n| n.parse::<i32>().ok()))
{
    tmp_map.insert(pair.next().unwrap(), pair.next().unwrap());
}
```

...which seems very unwieldy. Is there a way to collect this iterator into a `HashMap`?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f6a80f40ec0ba0380c9c539a4b740ecb&version=undefined)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HashMap` implements [`FromIterator<(K, V)>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#impl-FromIterator%3C(K%2C%20V)%3E). Then it's just a matter of converting the text into an iterator of tuples. I like using [`Itertools::tuples`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.1/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuples):

```
const INPUT: &str = r#"0: 3
1: 2
2: 4
4: 8
6: 5
8: 6"#;

extern crate itertools;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let z: HashMap<u8, u8> = INPUT
        .lines()
        .flat_map(|l| l.split(":"))
        .flat_map(|n| n.trim().parse())
        .tuples()
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", z);
}
```

See also:

- [How do I create a map from a list in a functional way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30441698/155423)

Comment: Thanks, `Itertools::tuples` is cool. I had tried `...().collect::<(i32, i32)>` to get those tuples but was informed that it was basically nonsense

Comment: Just as a note: I think this makes a flat stream of numbers, and then picks them in pairs. I.e. it doesn't care whether the input is `1: 2\n3: 4\n`, `1\n2\n3\n4\n` or `1: 2: 3: 4` (also it ignores all parse errors afaict).

Comment: @Stefan yep! The original code ignored the parse errors as well (`filter_map(|n| n.parse::<i32>().ok())`), I just wrote it shorter. It also makes the assumption that the key and the value are the same integer type.