# What is the best way to convert a vector of tuples into a hashmap with a value of a vector?

Tags: rust

I am pretty new to rust, so I have a bit of trouble with the borrow checker. I have a json object which is a vector of the form:
`Vec<(String, Option<char>, String)>`.
I want to be able to convert this vector into a hash map in order to allow for quick access of each element. Originally, each tuple was unique, and the user would pass a pair of a string and a char, so I had a hashmap of which was of the form `HashMap<(String, Option<char>), String>`. The conversion function was just an iteration over the original vector passed as a json object like so:

```
let new_transition_function: Vec<(String, Option<char>, String)> = origin
    .transition_function
    .iter()
    .map(|(x, y, z)| ((x.to_owned(), y.to_owned()), z.to_owned()))
    .collect();
```

However, when the third element is non-unique, the value is jsut replaced in the hashmap, when I need to keep each value. How can I most efficiently and idiomatically transform the old vector of `Vec<(String, Option<char>, String)>` to a `HashMap<(String, Option<char>), Vec<String>)>`?

Comment: It does not, thank you though. That question was asking what data structure they should use, when I already know which data structure I want to use. I am asking how can I convert that json object into my desired data structure. However, their solution and mine are identical, so that is neat.

Comment: Yes, but they also cover the 2 main ways to accomplish this. 1) Using a `HashMap<Key, Vec<Value>>` and using that with the `Entry` API or 2) Using the [`multimap`](https://crates.io/crates/multimap) crate

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there any way to create a multi map using the built in .iter() .map() and .collect() functions? I don't see too much documentation for it, but I can peek into the multimap source to check. Thank you for the help

Comment: If there isn't, you could always just replace the `map` with a `for_each` and call `insert` for each entry

Comment: Yeah, but that would require for it to be mutable and not purely functional, which is not best practice from what I understand. That was my first thought as well, coming from C/C++. However, after looking through the source, I saw that there is an extension for serde, which is the json serialization library I am using, so that circumvents my problem entirely. Thank you very much. If you make that a full answer I will pick it.

Comment: That's good. But do keep in mind that simply having some mutability in your code does not necessarily make it *worse/bad-practice*. There is no need to create a new answer here. The best option would be for you to accept the duplicate vote since the already existing answer is quite good and future readers can benefit from it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205411/discussion-between-roquentin-and-sshashank124).

Comment: [How do I create a map from a list in a functional way?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30441736/155423) covers the case where you want to use `collect` still.