# How do I cast a literal value to a trait object?

Tags: rust

I am trying to make this code more concise and to get rid of redundant variables. Is it possible to do so?

```
trait Foo {}
impl Foo for i32 {}
impl Foo for String {}

fn main() {
    let xi32: i32 = 10;
    let y = String::from("ooo");
    let mut foo_list: Vec<&Foo> = vec![];
    foo_list.push(&xi32 as &Foo);
    foo_list.push(&y as &Foo);
}
```

The following variant doesn't work:

```
foo_list.push(10 as Foo);
```

```
error[E0620]: cast to unsized type: `{integer}` as `Foo`
  --> src/main.rs:11:19
   |
11 |     foo_list.push(10 as Foo);
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^
   |
help: consider using a box or reference as appropriate
  --> src/main.rs:11:19
   |
11 |     foo_list.push(10 as Foo);
   |                   ^^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rust lets you take a reference to a temporary:

```
foo_list.push(&10 as &Foo);
```

This exact code won't work [until Rust 1.21](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38865), where the literal value `10` is automatically promoted to a static value and then a reference is taken to it.

Before Rust 1.21, the temporary ceases to exist at the end of the statement, so you'd end up with a dangling reference in your vector. Therefore, you **must** use a variable to extend the value's lifetime.

Comment: I want sugar, and sugar for literal hash maps too!

Comment: @DaneelS.Yaitskov [How do I create a HashMap literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27582739/155423)

Answer (score 4):

You can use boxed trait objects to store values in the vector:

```
let mut box_list: Vec<Box<Foo>> = vec![];
box_list.push(Box::new(42));
box_list.push(Box::new("forty two".to_owned()));
```