# Cast to unsized type: `std::io::Stdout` as `std::io::Write` error

Tags: casting, rust, traits

I am trying to cast `Stdout` to `Write`:

```
use std::io::{self, Write};

pub struct A<Output: Write> {
    output: Output,
}

impl<Output: Write> A<Output> {
    pub fn new() -> A<Output> {
        A {
            output: io::stdout() as Write,
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler is complaining:

```
error[E0620]: cast to unsized type: `std::io::Stdout` as `std::io::Write`
  --> src/main.rs:10:21
   |
10 |             output: io::stdout() as Write,
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
help: consider using a box or reference as appropriate
  --> src/main.rs:10:21
   |
10 |             output: io::stdout() as Write,
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I want to cast this and tried to do what the compiler suggested but then it is saying that the `as` keyword could only be used for primitives and that I should implement the `From` trait.

How could I cast the `Stdout` as a `Write` trait?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What makes something a "trait object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567849/what-makes-something-a-trait-object)

Comment: That is not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I cast a literal value to a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38294911/how-do-i-cast-a-literal-value-to-a-trait-object) (It asks about literals but the answers apply)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> cast `Stdout` to `Write`

This does not make sense because `Write` isn't a type that you cast *to*. `Write` is a trait. There are *trait objects* that are types though, such as `Box<Write>` or `&Write`. Re-read the [trait objects chapter of *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html) to refresh your memory on this topic. Rust 1.27 is going to improve the syntax here to make it more obvious as `Box<dyn Write>` / `&dyn Write`.

You could use `Box::new(io::stdout()) as Box<Write>`, but you'll quickly run into  ["Expected type parameter" error in the constructor of a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551177/155423).

```
impl A<Box<Write>> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        A {
            output: Box::new(io::stdout()) as Box<Write>,
        }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [What makes something a "trait object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27567849/155423)
- [Why is `let ref a: Trait = Struct` forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36057645/155423)
- ["Expected type parameter" error in the constructor of a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551177/155423)

Comment: Thanks that is answering my question. Thought of a trait more like an interface. So when I cast to Write I can use those methods withs where implemented for stdout.

Comment: @TimonPost a trait *is* like an interface, but an interface is not a concrete concept that can be created. A trait object is that concrete value.