# Custom literals via Rust macros?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

Is it possible in Rust to define a macro that can parse custom literals, e.g. something along the lines of

```
vector!(3x + 15y)
```

To clarify, I would like to be able to get as close to the above syntax as one can (within the realm of what is possible of course).

Comment: Are you asking about *this specific syntax* (no, `3x` is not a valid token) or about custom literals *in general* (sure, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27582993/3650362) for example)?

Comment: This specific syntax (or something similar at least); edited the question to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: @trentcl `3x` is a valid token, and the [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/tokens.html#suffixes) explicitly says that macros are allowed to accept literals with arbitrary suffixes. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to assume that by "custom literal", you specifically mean "a regular Rust literal (excluding raw literals), immediately followed by a custom identifier". This includes:

- `"str"x`, a string literal `"str"` with custom suffix `x`
- `123x`, a numeric literal `123` with custom suffix `x`
- `b"bytes"x`, a byte literal `b"bytes"` with custom suffix `x`

If the above is a sufficient definition for you, then you're lucky, as the above are indeed all valid literal tokens in Rust, according to [the Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/tokens.html#suffixes):

> A suffix is a non-raw identifier immediately (without whitespace) following the primary part of a literal.
>
> **Any kind of literal (string, integer, etc) with any suffix is valid as a token, and can be passed to a macro without producing an error. The macro itself will decide how to interpret such a token and whether to produce an error or not.**
>
> However, suffixes on literal tokens parsed as Rust code are restricted. Any suffixes are rejected on non-numeric literal tokens, and numeric literal tokens are accepted only with suffixes from the list below.

So Rust *explicitly*  allows macros to support custom literals.

Now, how would you go about writing such a macro? You can't write a declarative macro with `macro_rules!`, since it's not possible to detect and manipulate custom literal suffixes with its simple pattern matching. However, it is possible to write a [*procedural macro*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html) that does this.

I won't go into too much detail about how to write procedural macros, since that would be too much to write in a single StackOverflow answer. However, I'll give you this example of a procedural macro that does something along the lines of what you asked for, as a starting point. It takes any custom integer literals `123x` or `123y` in the given expression, and transforms them into the function calls `x_literal(123)` and `y_literal(123)` instead:

```
extern crate proc_macro;

use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::ToTokens;
use syn::{
    parse_macro_input, parse_quote,
    visit_mut::{self, VisitMut},
    Expr, ExprLit, Lit, LitInt,
};


// actual procedural macro
#[proc_macro]
pub fn vector(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let mut input = parse_macro_input!(input as Expr);
    LiteralReplacer.visit_expr_mut(&mut input);
    input.into_token_stream().into()
}

// "visitor" that visits every node in the syntax tree
// we add our own behavior to replace custom literals with proper Rust code
struct LiteralReplacer;

impl VisitMut for LiteralReplacer {
    fn visit_expr_mut(&mut self, i: &mut Expr) {
        if let Expr::Lit(ExprLit { lit, .. }) = i {
            match lit {
                Lit::Int(lit) => {
                    // get literal suffix
                    let suffix = lit.suffix();
                    // get literal without suffix
                    let lit_nosuffix = LitInt::new(lit.base10_digits(), lit.span());

                    match suffix {
                        // replace literal expression with new expression
                        "x" => *i = parse_quote! { x_literal(#lit_nosuffix) },
                        "y" => *i = parse_quote! { y_literal(#lit_nosuffix) },
                        _ => (), // other literal suffix we won't modify
                    }
                }

                _ => (), // other literal type we won't modify
            }
        } else {
            // not a literal, use default visitor method
            visit_mut::visit_expr_mut(self, i)
        }
    }
}
```

The macro would for example transform `vector!(3x + 4y)` into `x_literal(3) + y_literal(4)`.

Comment: This works great! I addition, I discovered that I have to use nightly with `feature(proc_macro_hygiene)` as procedural macros cannot normally be used as an expression.

Comment: @MrMobster That's great to hear! You can also use the [`proc-macro-hack`](https://docs.rs/proc-macro-hack/0.5.14/proc_macro_hack/index.html) crate as a workaround to have expression macros in Rust stable.