# Is there an equivalent macro for linked list like vec! in Rust

Tags: rust, linked-list, macros

So for easy initialization of a vector there is there vec! macro.

```rust
let mut vec_of_zeroes: Vec<usize> = vec![0;10];
```

I was wondering if there was an easy standard macro for initializing a linked list too?

```rust
use std::collections::LinkedList;

let mut list_of_zeroes: LinkedList<usize> = /*macro here?*/;
```

If not, no worries. Thanks for you time.

Comment: `let list_of_zeroes: LinkedList<usize> = [1usize, 2, 3, 4, 5].iter().copied().collect();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no linked list macro, but you could use the [`.extend()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html) method to achieve something similar:

```rust
use std::collections::LinkedList;

fn main() {
    let mut a: LinkedList<u32> = LinkedList::new();
    
    a.extend(&[0; 10]);
    
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fd79e928c8dc2bc0c80690939b0bd816)

If you want to have a single line initialization, you could use some other iterator methods as suggested by @Stargateur in the comments. This method also allows the variable to be immutable, if you wanted that for some reason.

```rust
use std::collections::LinkedList;

fn main() {
    let a: LinkedList<u32> = [0; 10].iter().copied().collect();
    
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=896ff6a10be1d6b80f37030dbf870fd1)

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no such macro in the standard library. Indeed, there is no analogous macro for any other data structure, [even `HashMap` / `BTreeMap`, which are much more frequently used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582739/how-do-i-create-a-hashmap-literal).

However, the crate [`velcro`](https://docs.rs/velcro/0.5.3/velcro/) provides a [`linked_list!`](https://docs.rs/velcro/0.5.3/velcro/macro.linked_list.html) macro that does what you want (and has some other neat features).

Note that `std::collections::LinkedList` lacks some features that make linked lists attractive - there is no cursor-based API, for instance. In most cases you should probably use `Vec` or `VecDeque` instead.