# How can I define Rust structure literals similar to Python's?

Tags: json, rust, hashmap, literals

I want to initialize a Rust variable with a literal.

[Shepmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155423/shepmaster) [guesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582739/how-do-i-create-a-hashmap-literal) that Rust has no map literal because:

> the fact that there are multiple data structures that act maplike
> (such as both BTreeMap and HashMap) would make it hard to pick one.

But Rust says ["you should probably just use Vec or HashMap"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/index.html), meaning that if they are good enough for most purposes, then using them when initializing from a literal value should usually work just fine.

The example map initialization is clumsy, but printing it produces a more concise representation:

`{"Mars": 1.5, "Mercury": 0.4, "Earth": 1.0, "Venus": 0.7}`.

```rust
fn main() {
use std::collections::HashMap;

let solar_distance = HashMap::from([
    ("Mercury", 0.4),
    ("Venus", 0.7),
    ("Earth", 1.0),
    ("Mars", 1.5),
]);

println!("{:?}", solar_distance)
}
```

In Python `x = {"Mars": 1.5, "Mercury": 0.4, "Earth": 1.0, "Venus": 0.7}` would initialize a dict variable.  It would be nice if a future version of Rust would accept nested list and map literals to initialize the corresponding default Vec and HashMap structures.

Is a concise nested literal format on the Rust feature roadmap?

A second-best solution would initialize structures from a JSON string (perhaps with some syntactic sugar to avoid quote-escape hell):

```rust
fn main() {
use std::collections::HashMap;

let x = String::from("{'Venus': 0.7, 'Mars': 1.5, 'Mercury': 0.4, 'Earth': 1.0}");
println!("{:?}", x);

let solar_distance = HashMap::from(x);
println!("{:?}", solar_distance);
}
```

But this fails with:

```
    |
7   | let solar_distance = HashMap::from(x);
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<String>` is not implemented for `HashMap<_, _, _>`
```

Has anyone written a method to initialize a nested vec/hash variable from a JSON string?

Comment: Did you consider using `Serde`?

Comment: Re: closing line -- just because `println!` makes output that _looks_ like JSON given a trivial example, that's a far cry from being able to safely assert that the output _is_ JSON; the latter requires specific choices around handling of non-ASCII characters, backslash-escape sequences, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to initialize a `HashMap` concisely (similar to `vec![]`), take a look at https://crates.io/crates/hmap. It does basically exactly what you're describing.

If you want to work with `serde_json`, you can use the `json!()` macro provided by that library:

```rust
let x = json!({
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": [1, 2, 3],
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  That answered the question, which I totally mangled while writing.  My motivation was to see if Rust had a native literal format like Python, which looks to the user like JSON with single quotes except that it is an actual literal structure, not a string containing JSON-ish characters.

Comment: @Dave, insofar as you can edit the question to better describe your real question while not invalidating any non-deleted answers, I'd urge you to do so. I already did a light edit to the title, but there's more to do in the body as well.

Comment: Note that `json!` gives you a `serde_json::Value`, which is an enum that can store all six primitive JSON types. If you want to get the `serde_json::Map` out, you'll need to use a `match` to destructure the `Value::Object(map)` variant.