# Idiomatic way to create a constant HashMap with values in Rust

Tags: rust, hashmap

I want to know what is the idiomatic way to create a constant Hashmap with values in Rust?

I have an implementation like:

```
const LOOKUP_TABLE: HashMap<usize, f64> = HashMap::from([
    (1, 1.1),   // Values are randomly put
    (2, 2.2),
]);
```

and I get an error:

```
error[E0015]: cannot call non-const fn `<HashMap<usize, f64> as From<[(usize, f64); 12]>>::from` in constants
  --> 
   |
18 |   const LOOKUP_TABLE: HashMap<usize, f64> = HashMap::from([
   |  _________________________________________________^
19 | |     (1, 1.1),
20 | |     (2, 2.2),
31 | | ]);
   | |__^
   |
   = note: calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
```

Comment: I usually use [`lazy_static`](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/latest/lazy_static/).

Comment: Or better, [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell).

Comment: ....aaaand now I'm wishing Rust had more data literals in the syntax.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582739/how-do-i-create-a-hashmap-literal

Answer (score 4):

Rust's `std::collections::HashMap` cannot be used to create a const HashMap directly, because it requires dynamic memory allocation, which is not allowed for const values.

One possible way is to use the `lazy_static` crate, which allows you to initialize a static variable lazily at runtime. For example:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    static ref COUNTRIES: HashMap<usize, f64> = {
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        m.insert(1, 1.1);
        m.insert(2, 2.2);
    };
}
```

Another possible way is to use the `phf` crate, which allows you to create compile-time static collections. For example:

```rust
use phf::{phf_map};

static COUNTRIES: phf::Map<usize, f64> = phf_map! {
    1 => 1.1,
    2 => 2.2,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the crate I've developed, [`maparr`](https://github.com/zhiburt/maparr):

```rust
use maparr::maparr;

maparr!(
    Continents<usize>;
    ASIA,
    AFRICA,
    AMERICA_NORTH,
    AMERICA_SOUTH,
    ANTARCTICA,
    EUROPE,
    AUSTRALIA,
);

fn main() {
    let mut continents = maparr!(
        Continents;
        ASIA                = 17_212_000,
        AFRICA              = 11_608_000,
        AMERICA_NORTH       = 9_365_000,
        AMERICA_SOUTH       = 6_880_000,
        ANTARCTICA          = 5_100_000,
        EUROPE              = 3_837_000,
        AUSTRALIA           = 2_968_000,
    );

    continents.set(Continents::ASIA, 17_212_001);
    assert_eq!(continents[Continents::ASIA], 17_212_001);

    continents = continents.map(|value| value * 2);
    assert_eq!(continents[Continents::ASIA], 17_212_001 * 2);
}
```

Comment: You must **explicitly** disclose that any linked resources are your own. Otherwise, your post(s) may be flagged as spam.

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).

Comment: As @AdrianMole said it's been developed by me. (Not sure where it shall be stated)

Comment: @Zhiburt in the post in which you're telling the community about your crate.