# How to store predefined instances of a struct in a way that they can be referenced by name?

Tags: rust

I would like to store many predefined instances of a struct as constants and group them in a way that I am able to reference them by name.

I could achieve it like this:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct MyStruct {
    // ...
}

const INSTANCES: HashMap<&str, MyStruct> = [
    ("Instance1", MyStruct {
        // fields...
    }),
    ("Instance2", MyStruct {
        // fields...
    }),
    ("Instance3", MyStruct {
        // fields...
    }),
    // Add more instances as needed
].iter().cloned().collect();

fn main() {
    let instance = INSTANCES.get("Instance1");
    // ...
}
```

Or this:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    // ...
}

enum MyStructInstance {
    Instance1,
    Instance2,
    Instance3,
    // Add more instances as needed
}

impl MyStructInstance {
    fn get_instance(&self) -> MyStruct {
        match self {
            MyStructInstance::Instance1 => MyStruct {
                // fields...
            },
            MyStructInstance::Instance2 => MyStruct {
                // fields...
            },
            MyStructInstance::Instance3 => MyStruct {
                // fields...
            },
            // ...
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let instance1 = MyStructInstance::Instance1.get_instance();
    // ...
}
```

But it does not seem well formed. What is the standard way for storing a named list of predefined instances?

Comment: What about using a separate `const` for each one?

Comment: I am looking for a better alternative, because I might have 40+ of them

Comment: Well, it's not worse than using an enum or map.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Idiomatic way to create a constant HashMap with values in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76039999/idiomatic-way-to-create-a-constant-hashmap-with-values-in-rust)

Comment: @drewtato It does not

Comment: What is different with your question?

Comment: I have a similar problem, my first thought was Vec<MyStruct>, but i wish i could put all instances in an enum as values, but that's not possible, i guess. I am still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to store many predefined instances of a struct as *constants* and *group* them in a way that I am able to *reference* them by *name*.

```rust
pub mod group {
    pub struct MyStruct {
        // ...
    }

    pub const Instance1: MyStruct = MyStruct {};
    
    pub const Instance2: MyStruct = MyStruct {};
    
    pub const Instance3: MyStruct = MyStruct {};
}

fn main() {
    let instance1 = group::Instance1;
    let instance2 = group::Instance2;
    // ...
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%23%5Ballow%28non_upper_case_globals%29%5D%0Apub+mod+group+%7B%0A++++pub+struct+MyStruct+%7B%0A++++++++%2F%2F+...%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++pub+const+Instance1%3A+MyStruct+%3D+MyStruct+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++%0A++++pub+const+Instance2%3A+MyStruct+%3D+MyStruct+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++%0A++++pub+const+Instance3%3A+MyStruct+%3D+MyStruct+%7B%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn+main%28%29+%7B%0A++++let+_instance1+%3D+group%3A%3AInstance1%3B%0A++++let+_instance2+%3D+group%3A%3AInstance2%3B%0A++++%2F%2F+...%0A%7D%0A). If you want to modify them, you can use `static` with `unsafe` updates. You may implement `FromStr` trait for `MyStruct`, if you need conversions from strings.