How do I read values directly into a global HashMap?
How do you create a global variable that is a HashMap and is populated with data directly? The code below has a local variable 'e' that works as intended. However, I am struggling to make it a global variable.
use std::collections::HashMap;

const E: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::from([("Ar", "Argon"),
    ("Ce", "Cerium"), ("Br", "Bromine")] );


fn main() {
    let e = HashMap::from([("Ar", "Argon"),
    ("Ce", "Cerium"), ("Br", "Bromine")] );
    
    println!("{:?}", e["Ce"]);
    println!("{:?}", E["Ce"]);
}


I receive 'error: cannot call non-const fn create_some in constants'. Can you provide a quick and easy way of doing this job?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76039999/idiomatic-way-to-create-a-constant-hashmap-with-values-in-rust

You can't do this at compile time because the hash function uses random input generated at runtime to prevent certain types of attacks or performance bugs.
The fix here is to use something like LazyLock which defers initialization until the first access.
use std::{collections::HashMap, sync::LazyLock};

static E: LazyLock<HashMap<&str, &str>> =
    LazyLock::new(|| HashMap::from([("Ar", "Argon"), ("Ce", "Cerium"), ("Br", "Bromine")]));

fn main() {
    let e = HashMap::from([("Ar", "Argon"), ("Ce", "Cerium"), ("Br", "Bromine")]);

    println!("{:?}", e["Ce"]);
    println!("{:?}", E["Ce"]);
}

(Playground)
